# How to generate samples from distribution function of data points by PyMC3

Tags: python, sampling, pymc3, pymc, mcmc

I have a density distribution function from data, which means that I cannot express its analytical form. If I want to generate 1000 samples by this distribution function, what should I do. It seems like PyMC3 is capable with doing that but I don't know how exactly.

To simplify problem, we can start with one dimensional distribution but I need to use high dimensional distribution later.

Note that I don't have any analytical model. I only have distribution functions from data.

I have tried to use pm.Densityhist and pm.sample but I cannot generate samples.

Comment: have you made any progress with this?  sampling from a KDE would be an easy approach, but if the data is too sparse to reliably get a KDE another approach would be to fit a model and use it to generate more samples in a similar manner to doing a [posterior predictive check](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/125576/17060)

Answer (score 2):

One option you can use is to perform [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). This does not require PyMC3 or an MCMC approach. You can generate a kernel density estimate from your samples using the [`gaussian_kde`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) function within SciPy (other KDE methods exist, such as the [`KernelDensity`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity) class in scikit-learn) and then draw new samples from that estimate. For example, if your samples were in a list/NumPy array called `x`, then you could do the following:

```py
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

kde = gaussian_kde(x)  # generate the KDE

# draw 1000 samples from the KDE
newsamples = kde.resample(1000)
```